# Show EULA in ClickOnce

Tags: c#, clickonce, eula

I want to show an EULA (End-User License Agreement) window before installing the application with Clickonce.

I googled a lot and chose to follow this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/301d7b68-914b-4a05-8f2b-d9aa53f69cca/sneaky-way-to-get-an-eula-displayed-for-your-clickonce-application-in-vs2005?forum=winformssetup).

I combined the solutions of the first reply of that discussion and the one with eula.bat. It looks great now but I want to customize the window more.

[image: Screenshot of EULA Window]

1. I prefer not to show the button View EULA for printing.
2. I want to make the EULA textbox can't be copyed.
3. I want an alternative solution other than eula.bat as it will popup a window.

Product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 

<Product
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" ProductCode="EULA.Bootstrap.Component">
  <!-- Defines list of files to be copied on build -->
  <PackageFiles>
    <PackageFile Name="en/eula.bat"/>
        <PackageFile Name="en/eula.rtf"/>
  </PackageFiles>

  <Commands>
    <Command PackageFile="en/eula.bat"
       Arguments='' >
        <ExitCodes>
          <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
          <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
        </ExitCodes>
     </Command>
  </Commands>
</Product>
```

Package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" Name="DisplayName" Culture="Culture" LicenseAgreement="eula.rtf">
    <PackageFiles>
        <PackageFile Name="eula.rtf"/>
    <PackageFile Name="eula.bat"/>
    </PackageFiles>

  <!-- Defines a localizable string table for error messages and url's  -->
  <Strings>
    <String Name="DisplayName">End User License Agreement</String>
    <String Name="Culture">en</String>
  </Strings>
</Package>
```

You can follow that link and copy them to the right place such as C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages if you are using VS 2013.

Comment: You found a solution yet?