# ClickOnce Installation won't allow change to EULA

Tags: clickonce, bootstrapper

I'm publishing an application with ClickOnce - VS 2022, .NET Framework 4.7.2.  Adding a EULA as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072372/show-eula-in-clickonce). The EULA is an .rtf file.  It works fine, but if I edit the rtf file, republish and run the setup bootstrapper, it declines to install, with the message, "Setup has detected that the file . . . eula.rtf has either changed since it was initially published or may be corrupt.  Click OK to retry the download, or Cancel to exit setup."  It has indeed changed.  Both builds were signed with the same certificate.  Is there a way to deploy the updated EULA?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I made a new package with a different name and the updated EULA, and that works, but if anyone knows an easier way I'd be grateful to learn it. By the way, if anyone is trying this now, in VS 2022 the bootstrapper packages are in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages.